# Laravel custom password reset

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, passwords, reset

i did this:

```
public function ForgotPassword(Request $request) {
        $template_data = [
            'template'  =>  $this->template->ConstructArrayTemplate()
        ];     

        $rules = ['email' => 'required|exists:accounts|email']; 

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        $errors = $this->sortErrors ( $validator, array('email') );

        if ( $errors ) {
            $template_data [ 'Errs' ] = $errors;
            $template_data [ 'template' ] [ 'page_name' ] = 'Sign up';

            return view('forgot_password', $template_data);
        } 

        $response = $this->passwords->sendResetLink($request->only('email'));

        switch ($response)
        {
            case PasswordBroker::RESET_LINK_SENT:
                return redirect('');
        }
    }
```

and because of:

```
$response = $this->passwords->sendResetLink($request->only('email'));
```

I get next error:

> InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View
>   [auth.emails.password] not found.

Comment: check if you have the this file: `resources/views/auth/emails/password.blade.php`

Comment: and if I want another path?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a password reset email sent, you need to provide a view that will be used to generate email content.

You should put this template in **resources/views/auth/emails/password.blade.php**.

In this template you can reference the reset token as **$token** and the user object with **$user**.

Comment: And if I want another path?

Comment: Another path to...?

Comment: for example, I want for email.forgotpassword